# How to separately create a presigned URL query parameter?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Currently I am generating the authenticated URL as :

```
$this->s3Client = new S3Client($this->options);
$cmd = $this->s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
    'Key'    => $object_key
]);
$request = $this->s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, PRESIGNED_URL_VALIDITY);
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Is there a way I could generate the query parameters in the authenticated URL on my own an not using `createPresignedRequest`.

I need to separately create :

```
?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=
&X-Amz-Date=20130721T201207Z
&X-Amz-Expires=86400
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Signature=<signature-value>
```

and the append it to the bucket file path to make it into the presigned request.

Comment: The S3 API documentation explains all of those parameters and how to populate them, in the section called [Authenticating Requests: Using Query Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).  Using this documentation, it is possible to create pre-signed URLs for S3 using no SDK code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you mean by "generate the query parameters in the authenticated URL on my own". AWS uses [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org) to deal with generating signatures and building signed URLs.

You could create signed URLs entirely w/o PHP, for e.g. on a Linux command line using the `openssl` command. Check this for a bash example: https://github.com/gdbtek/aws-tools/blob/master/sign_s3_url.bash.

You can also use PHP w/o the S3Client to generate signed URLs using the [PHP OpenSSL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) and utilising `openssl_*` functions.

Comment: Could you show me an example, where I could build a URL that lasts for example `2 days`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that cannot be done using the PHP SDK S3Client?

Comment: I have a `s3 file URL`. I want to convert that into the presigned URL.

Comment: Refer to @Michael - sqlbot's comment. There is a link to the documentation.